# Jquery number Format is currency

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have amount value like 100,000 and I need to use as currency like 100,000, so anybody help me about this issue or bug?

Comment: Please explain your question.It is not clear.

Comment: hi, i have value 1000 so how can convert into 1,000

Comment: If you [google](https://www.google.co.uk/#safe=on&q=jquery+string+format+currency) you will find plenty of suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var str = "1234567";
var n = str.length%3;
var res = str.substring(0, n) + "," ;
for(var i = 0 ;i<str.length/3 -1;i++)
{
    res = res + "," + str.substring(n,n+3);
    n = n+3;
}

print res;
```

Comment: sorry for detail, because my value is dynamic so sometime i have value like 1,000 and also l00,000 ,209,099

Comment: You can pass the value to "str" variable.

Comment: can you post your code?you should can pass the value to "str" variable.